# VS2010 - C - process.h - "joining" threads started with _beginthread

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, join

I'm trying to use the threading library of Windows (in VS2010) for the first time. But I think I'm missing something... How do I join the created threads? How do I prevent the main()-Programm (or other "higher" function) from exiting, when there are threads still running?
Hope someone can help me with an answer or a link (msdn and a few others weren't helpful).
thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Untested, no error checking code:

```
HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthread(Thread, 0, NULL);
WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);     // wait until the thread has finished
```

Comment: nice thanks! Didn't know that I need to include <windows.h> too... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is safer to use `_beginthreadex` and `WaitForSingleObject` together as `_beginthread` automatically closes the thread handle. In case the thread ("Thread") exits too quickly, the thread handle can be assigned to another thread or become invalid and then `WaitForSingleObject` may go to undefined behavior (crash or hang).
With `_beginthreadex` we can keep the thread handle even after the thread exits. Note that with `_beginthreadex` we must call `CloseHandle` while with `_beginthread`, we do not need to do that.